# How to setup up .htaccess rewrites for http and https on the same site?

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some issues with *htaccess* rewrites i need to redirect different parts of my site to HTTPS rather than HTTP, for example login and news sections. I'm not sure how to go about doing this in the correct manner.

So at the moment I have

```
RewriteRule   ^login/?$  index.php?p=login [R,L]
```

I would like to redirect this to HTTPS, I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/index.php?p=login [R,L]
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? I have rewrite on and all other settings as they work.

Also is there anyway to get *htaccess* to use a different set of rules if HTTPS is set to when it is not?

Update:

So what I want to do is rewrite `http://www.site.tld/login/` rewrite to `https://www.site.tld/login/code` and then further rewrite to `https://www.site.tld/index.php?p=login`. So the user sees: `https://www.site.tld/login/` but it is actually doing `https://www.site.tld/index.php?p=login`

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what actually happens? No redirection? Redirect loop? What is the `/code` part for in the middle step?

Answer (score 1):

First, redirect /login to https /login/code

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login/code  [R=301,L]
```

You can also force /login/code to redirect to https in case the type in http /login/code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule ^login/code$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login/code  [R=301,L]
```

Then, you can rewrite /login/code

```
RewriteRule ^login/code$ /index.php?p=login [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it all with re-writes.  I have the following in the header of my php files:

```
  if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!="localhost") 
 {
   header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 }
```

And then this in my .htaccess

```
#re-write /login/username to /login.htm?login=username
RewriteRule ^/?login/([^/\.]+)/?$ /login.htm?login=$1 [NC,L]
#re-write /login and /login/ account-login.htm
RewriteRule ^/?login/?$ /account-login.htm [NC,L]
```